# how to get Twilio to text me if a product im monitoring is in stock

Tags: python, text, twilio, monitoring

Hi i am currently monitoring a specific product on a website. I am able to get twilio to text me by just running the script but it doesn't update me if a product is instock or not. Here is the code that matters for this process:

```
import requests,json,re,time,sys
import twilio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from twilio.rest import Client


timeout = [] #Define global timeout list, this list is used to blacklist pops once they've sent one notification so you don't get 100 notifications for an in stock pop.

def url_to_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def hottopic_stock(url):
    soup = url_to_html(url)
    html_source = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "availability-msg"})
    match = re.search(r'\bIn Stock\b',str(html_source))
    if match: #Return true if In Stock
        return False


def CheckFunko(Site, Title, url):
    global timout
    print("Checking: "+Site+" "+Title+" "+url)

#this is where I want to combine the functions
    if Site == 'Hot Topic':
        status = hottopic_stock(url)
    else:
        status = False
    if status == True:
        client = Client("Api key, twilio account number")
        client.messages.create(to="My phone number",
                               from_="Twillo Phone number",
                               body="Duffer Brothers in stock!"
```

Comment: There is more code that i didnt include bit I didn't think it was nessisary to add

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your `hottopic_stock` function, as it only returns `False` (if the regex matches) or `None` (if the regex does not match), while in your sending code you check, whether status is `True`, which will never be the case. Maybe try this (I am assuming that the thing is in stock, if the regex does match and did not test this code):

```
def hottopic_stock(url):
    soup = url_to_html(url)
    html_source = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "availability-msg"})
    match = re.search(r'\bIn Stock\b',str(html_source))
    return match is not None
```